# How to solve this Riccati equation $4xy'=4x^2y^2-4y-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation below
$$4xy'=4x^2y^2-4y-1$$

So far I am having a hard time in spotting a specific solution which I can use to find the general solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is
$$
-\frac{\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}-i c\right)}{2 x}
$$
To get it change the variable $z(x)=x y(x)$ after that it is standard

Comment: how did you come up with $z(x)=xy(x)$?

Comment: by looking on the equation it is clear that $x$ always comes together with $y$

Comment: A specific solution would be $1\over 2x$